# Void pointer casted to some other pointer type T does not behave like T

Tags: c, pointers, casting

I'm trying to make a generic circular buffer using a void pointer buffer and I get some issues I don't understand.

If I use a double pointer for my buffer, my circular buffer behaves as expected (see test1 below), but if I use a void pointer, I get a wrong behaviour (see test2), although all the void pointers are casted to double pointers. What's wrong with my casting?

One more question: in `circular_buffer_write_chunk` I'm using a double pointer to pass the data. I need to pass it as with a void pointer in order to make it generic. I would then have to cast it dynamically in the function to the type of the buffer (which could be `double` or `int`) in order to get the pointer arithmetic working. How can I do that? How can I get the type of the pointer to the buffer and then cast my data pointer to that type?

Any comment or suggestion welcome.

**test1** Running `circular_buffer_test()` with buffer as double pointer

```
*** circular_buffer test***
capacity: 12

Write 5 values
cb[0]=0.000000
cb[1]=1.000000
cb[2]=2.000000
cb[3]=3.000000
cb[4]=4.000000
cb[5]=0.000000
cb[6]=0.000000
cb[7]=0.000000
cb[8]=0.000000
cb[9]=0.000000
cb[10]=0.000000
cb[11]=0.000000

Write 10 values
cb[0]=12.000000
cb[1]=13.000000
cb[2]=14.000000
cb[3]=3.000000
cb[4]=4.000000
cb[5]=5.000000
cb[6]=6.000000
cb[7]=7.000000
cb[8]=8.000000
cb[9]=9.000000
cb[10]=10.000000
cb[11]=11.000000

Test done
```

**test2** Running `circular_buffer_test()` with buffer as void pointer. Why is that different?

```
*** circular_buffer test***
capacity: 12

Write 5 values
cb[0]=0.000000
cb[1]=1.000000
cb[2]=2.000000
cb[3]=3.000000
cb[4]=4.000000
cb[5]=0.000000
cb[6]=0.000000
cb[7]=0.000000
cb[8]=0.000000
cb[9]=0.000000
cb[10]=0.000000
cb[11]=0.000000

Write 10 values
cb[0]=12.000000
cb[1]=13.000000
cb[2]=14.000000
cb[3]=0.000000 // ?
cb[4]=0.000000 // ?
cb[5]=0.000000 // ?
cb[6]=0.000000 // ?
cb[7]=0.000000 // ?
cb[8]=0.000000 // ?
cb[9]=0.000000 // ?
cb[10]=0.000000 // ?
cb[11]=0.000000 // ?

Test done
```

**circular_buffer.c**

```
#include "circular_buffer.h"

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct
{
     double *buffer;
     double *buffer_end;
     unsigned int capacity;
     double *read_ptr;
     double *write_ptr;
     unsigned int count;
} circular_buffer;

/*

// Why doesn't this behave like with double pointer, since it's casted in circular_buffer_init_double?

typedef struct
{
     void *buffer;
     void *buffer_end;
     unsigned int capacity;
     void *read_ptr;
     void *write_ptr;
     unsigned int count;
} circular_buffer;

*/

void circular_buffer_init_double(circular_buffer *cb, unsigned int capacity)
{
    cb->buffer = (double*) malloc(sizeof(double) * capacity);
    cb->buffer_end = (double*) (cb->buffer + capacity);
    cb->capacity = capacity;
    cb->read_ptr = (double*) (cb->buffer);
    cb->write_ptr = (double*) (cb->buffer);
    cb->count = 0;
}

void circular_buffer_destroy(circular_buffer *cb){
    free(cb->buffer);
    cb->buffer = NULL;
}

int circular_buffer_is_full(circular_buffer *cb) {
    return cb->count == cb->capacity;
}

int circular_buffer_is_empty(circular_buffer *cb) {
    return cb->count == 0;
}

unsigned int circular_buffer_write_chunk(circular_buffer* cb, double *data, unsigned int type_size,
    unsigned int num_elements){

    if( num_elements > cb->capacity ) return 0;

    if( cb->write_ptr + num_elements > cb->buffer_end ){

    unsigned int write_ptr_to_buffer_end = cb->buffer_end - cb->write_ptr;
    unsigned int write_ptr_position = cb->write_ptr - cb->buffer;

    memcpy( cb->write_ptr, data, write_ptr_to_buffer_end * type_size );
    memcpy( cb->buffer, data + write_ptr_to_buffer_end,
        ( num_elements - write_ptr_to_buffer_end) * type_size );
    cb->write_ptr = cb->buffer + num_elements - write_ptr_to_buffer_end;
    }
    else{
    memcpy( cb->write_ptr, data, type_size * num_elements );
    cb->write_ptr += num_elements;
    if( cb->write_ptr == cb->buffer_end ){
        cb->write_ptr = cb->buffer;
    }
    }

    if( circular_buffer_is_full(cb) ) cb->read_ptr = cb->write_ptr;

    cb->count = cb->count + num_elements > cb->capacity ? cb->capacity : cb->count + num_elements;

    return num_elements;
}

void circular_buffer_test(){

    fprintf(stdout, "*** circular_buffer test***\n");

    circular_buffer *cb = malloc(sizeof(circular_buffer));
    circular_buffer_init_double(cb, 12);
    fprintf(stdout, "capacity: %d\n", cb->capacity);

    int i;
    double *w1 = malloc(sizeof(double) * 5);
    for(i=0; i<5; i++) w1[i] = (double) i;

    fprintf(stdout, "\nWrite 5 values\n");
    circular_buffer_write_chunk(cb, w1, sizeof(double), 5);
    for(i=0; i<12; i++) fprintf(stdout, "cb[%d]=%f\n", i, ((double *)cb->buffer)[i]);

    fprintf(stdout, "\nWrite 10 values\n");
    double *w2 = malloc(sizeof(double) * 10);
    for(i=5; i<15; i++) w2[i-5] = (double) i;
    circular_buffer_write_chunk(cb, w2, sizeof(double), 10);
    for(i=0; i<12; i++) fprintf(stdout, "cb[%d]=%f\n", i, ((double *)cb->buffer)[i]);   

    free(w1);
    free(w2);

    circular_buffer_destroy(cb);

    fprintf(stdout, "Test done\n");
}
```

Comment: Asking people to spot errors in your code is not especially productive. You should use the debugger (or add print statements) to isolate the problem, by tracing the progress of your program, and comparing it to what you expect to happen. As soon as the two diverge, then you've found your problem. (And then if necessary, you should construct a [minimal test-case](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).)

Comment: @OliCharlesworth I did spend some time trying to understand what's going on and I can't figure it out, that's why I'm asking. I guess it as something to do with the casting, but I can't understand why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pointer arithmetic with `void *` is not allowed in C:

```
 (double*) (cb->buffer + capacity);
```

`gcc` adds pointer arithmetic for `void *` as an extension by considering the size of `void` to be `1`.

Whether `buffer` is `void *` with `gcc` or `double *` the result of `cb->buffer + capacity` will be different. Use:

```
     ((double*) cb->buffer + capacity);
```

if `buffer` is `void *`.

Comment: @jul the pointer arithmetic is done with the declared type of `buffer` member (`void *` or `double *` in your `two circular_buffer` declaration). The `double *` cast after `malloc` is actually useless and can be removed (or *should* be removed, see http://c-faq.com/malloc/cast.html ).

Comment: I know that pointer arithmetic is not allowed with `void *` (that's also why I want to know how to cast `data` if it's a `void *` in my second question), but isn't the buffer pointer not void anymore at this point, since it's casted to double * in the line above: `cb->buffer = (double*) malloc(sizeof(double) * capacity);`?

Comment: but when using the generic `void *` buffer, I do want to cast  to `double *` in the `circular_buffer_init_double` so that my pointer arithmetic works. I can't do that?

Comment: Casting to `double *` in the assignment will have no effect. The type of the member will remain the declared type. For example: `cb->write_ptr = (double*) (cb->buffer);` the cast to `double *` is superfluous and the assignment is equivalent to `cb->write_ptr = cb->buffer;`.